# Math for VB.net Progressbar 0 to 100%

Tags: vb.net, math, progress-bar

I can not figure out the math that allows me to use a progress bar from 0-100% when the number is in the one hundred thousands.

I've tried:

```
156761 / 100 = 1567.61
156761 * 100 = 15676100
```

And I can not come up with anything else that allows that large of a number to be in the range of 0-100%.

Comment: where does the progress come from?

Comment: @JoshPart the progress comes from reading the lines in a text file - the 156761 "lines".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question correctly...
First, if what you want is to show a progressbar with some value that's not 100... why not simply set the progres bar's `Maximum` to your value (156761 in your example) and set `Value` to whatever progress it has?

Now, if the progress bar for whatever reason has to be fixed from 0 to 100, you can use:

`x / m * 100`

Where `m` is the max value and `x` the progress value.

Comment: I was unaware that you can do that with the process bar. I guess i am thinking back to VB6 days with the progress bar that had to be 0-100 and not over.

Comment: thanks for the help. Got it using **Dim thePercentage As Integer = progressCount / lineCount * 100**

Answer (score 2):

If you have a maximum value

```
x / max_value
```

And you want to convert it to percent.

```
y / 100
```

Then you need to do

```
x * 100 / max_value = y
```

Comment: What would be "x" in your example if max_value = 156761?

Comment: @StealthRT x would be the where you are in the process. lets say you need to load 3333 files, then if you want to know where the progress is for file 123 then x would be 123 and max_value would be 3333. y would be the amount based on 100%

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the maximum value your progress could reach (maybe a million) and divide by this to get a percentage of progress. So if your max was 1000000 you might do 100000/1000000= 0.1 to give 10%.

Comment: This assumes of course that your maximum value was fixed. If it isn't, substitute 1000000 for your actual maximum. In a nutshell, divide progress by maximum progress to get a percentage.